# I need to hook HTML input into Python and don't know how

Tags: python, html

I am working on a team project for a capstone course. We have decided to produce a self-hosted calendar app for college students. One team member has created HTML webpages for said self-hosted server. I need to hook button and text box input and output into a python program. We are using Starlette, but I cannot figure out how to get information from text boxes.

To give an example of what I need to do, the user will input information into a selection of text boxes. That info needs to be read and converted into variables, then sent into an SQL statement. I have the SQL done, I just don't know how to read the info from the HTML boxes and detect button input.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering it is necessary to know if you are using a python framework, ideally it would be enough to change the action of the form and connect it with a python function.

Here I leave you a tutorial to clarify a little bit the panorama.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlhg8HMZTOk

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention we are using Starlette.